# C# WriteLine method shows numbers inside brackets instead of what I want the to be replaced with

Tags: c#, templates, console.writeline

I just started learning C# and this is my code of a simple program for homework:

```
using System;

namespace Concatenate_Data
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
            int age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string town = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine($"You are {0} {1}, a {2}-years old person from {3}.", firstName, lastName, age, town);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of outputting for instance "You are Peter Johnson, a 20-years old person from Sofia.", it outputs "You are 0 1, a 2-years old person from 3. How can I fix this? I even copied the code 1:1 from the sample they gave us.

Comment: Remove the $ character before the string. This indicates [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: @Christie No, `Console.WriteLine` will do the `string.Format` for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` sign makes the string as an interpolated string. So it doesn't work as `string.Format()` works. You may refer documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

You may get the desired output when you write the code as per the following;

```
Console.WriteLine($"You are {firstName} {lastName}, a {age}-years old person from {town}.");
```